# ASP.NET Core 6 ODATA Count not returning a value

Tags: odata, asp.net-core-6.0

I have recently upgraded to `.NET 6 Core` Preview and I am experiencing some issues with ODATA. What use to work in `.NET Core 3.1` no longer works.

Here is my Startup snippet:
I also believe `EnableQueryFeatures()` allows for `Count` by default.

```
services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
    { 
        options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver();
    }).AddOData(opt => opt
          .EnableQueryFeatures()
          .AddRouteComponents("odata", GetEdmModel()
    );
```

I have the following Action Method and when called, the count is not returned
to the front end.

The **pageResult holds a count value**, but is not being returned to the front end,
when I inspect the result using Chrome DevTools.

```
[Route("odata/Tasks")]
public PageResult<TaskModel> AjaxListOData([FromQuery]ODataQueryOptions queryOptions)
{            
    var result = queryOptions.ApplyTo(dataContext.Tasks) as IEnumerable<TaskModel>;
    var pageResult = new PageResult<TaskModel>(
    result,
    null,
    count: Request.ODataFeature().TotalCount);

    return pageResult;
}
```

Comment: Reproduce the issue in a self-contained console project and submit a bug to the EF Core repo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved the problem by inheriting from `ODataController` and not from
`Controller`.

Comment: I'd like to share the reason for more audience. In the 8.x OData attribute routing, a new attribute `https://github.com/OData/AspNetCoreOData/blob/master/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData/Routing/Attributes/ODataAttributeRoutingAttribute.cs` is required either on controller or action. Since ODataController has it decorated, `[Route("odata/Tasks")]` is considered as OData attribute routing. If you only use `Controller` as base type, `[Route("odata/Tasks")]` goes to normal ASP.NET Core Routing.

Comment: @SamXu the ASP.NET Core OData docs need some love. The blog too. I've been using it for almost a year with .NET 6 and I've encountered a lot of breaking changes with no documentation or any announcements. Reading the sample project isn't documentation. People care about being able to use OData in general, not how to use custom formatters. They also care about using EF Core and `GroupBy`. We're talking about the basics